# Changing image opacity on hover of other elements in div

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create an effect used here so that when I hover over an image, the image opacity of the other images in the div changes but not the one hovered on. 
http://www.mintel.com/meet-the-team/page/2

```
$('myElement').set('opacity', 0.5).addEvents({
    mouseenter: function(){
```

I was going to use this function but this would change the whole divs opacity on hover 
Any suggestions on how I can start without using jquery?

Comment: I would suggest looking trough the javascript of the site you've linked. Seeing if you can find usefull stuff.

Comment: You can achieve that with pure CSS.

Comment: I did something similar: http://jsfiddle.net/a9zL7/

Comment: within css when I put the current opacity to 1 it's setting to the hover opacity . team_image {
 opacity:1;
 &:not(:hover) {
  opacity: 0.7;
 }
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pure CSS I don't think it's possible (because you need a selector not already implemented in CSS), you can use this pure js solution (no jQuery).

Code:

```
var rows = document.getElementsByClassName('demo');
for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].onmouseenter = function (event) {
        for (var j = 0; j < rows.length; j++) {
            if (rows[j]===this) continue
            rows[j].className += " other";
        }
    };

    rows[i].onmouseleave = function (event) {
        var hovers = document.getElementsByClassName('other');
        var len = hovers.length;
        for (var j = 0; j < len; j++) {
            hovers[0].className = hovers[0].className.replace(/\sother(\s|$)/, '');
        }
    };
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/7K2Z3/

Answer (score 0):

Let's say each block (image+text) will have `.item` class.

```
var item = $('.item');
item.on('hover', function() {
  item.css('opacity', '0.5');
  $(this).css('opacity', '1');
});
```

Hope you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks! and the hover function works for normal javascript or is that mootools?

Comment: Oh my, I've read "with Jquery", not without. But this can simply be done in pure js.

Answer (score 0):

Give all your images a common class.
Then you can use this selector:

```
$(".commonClass:not(:hover)")
```

This will select all images that are not hover.

With your `mouseenter` event you select all images that are not hover and apply the opacity change:

```
$(".commonClass:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '0.5');
```

Add the `mouseleave` event to restore the opacity:

```
 $(".commonClass:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '1');
```

So, you will end with something like this:

```
$('.commonClass').on('mouseenter', function () {
    $(".commonClass:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '0.5');
});

$('.commonClass').on('mouseleave', function () {
    $(".commonClass:not(:hover)").css('opacity', '1');
});
```